# React native orientation is not working || locking on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, orientation

I created an app with React-native. All pages I made are designed for portrait mode except 1 page. The page accessibility comes from a button onPress then navigates to the page, so I can't lock orientation on `Xcode`

I installed this package and *I can run it on android* perfectly

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';
```

When I tried it on IOS simulator on every page it can turns orientation to landscape.

I put this line in every pages componentdidmount but nothing changes.

```
componentDidMount() {
   

    Orientation.lockToPortrait()
...
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Anyone to help to lock orientation

Comment: What do you mean by this: 
`The page accessibility comes from a button onPress then navigates to the page, so I can't lock orientation on Xcode`

If you're on pure react native, you can simply lock it on Info.plist.

Comment: Oooo @FreakyCoder abi hayranınızım bu arada bir iki paketinizi kullanıyorum :).Basicly I got 10 pages. 9 of them portraid and 1 one them landscape screen. If i lock to portrait then landscape page does not works

Comment: Tesekkurler dostum @masterAvatarr :) 

Oh, I got it. Do you use expo or pure react native? Depends on that, I can help you.

Comment: Abi şu bounce ve herhangi bir componenti animated getirme çok güzel olmuş gerçekten. I'm using pure react-native.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey again @masterAvatarr,

I believe that this is what you're looking for, if you need something else please explain it to me :) We can make it happen.

I made a simple example for you.

https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-portrait-locker-example

I use [React Native Orientation Locker Library](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker)

The important parts are:

- Make sure that you linked the library manually (check AppDelegate.m)
- You need to make a logic for unlocking and lock the portrait mode depends on your use-case

Please take a look at `HomeScreen` and `DetailScreen`

```
import Orientation from "react-native-orientation-locker";


React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action
      Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
      Orientation.lockToPortrait();
    });

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

**Note:** There is a little GIF Demo on the Github Repo

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm using class component almost everypage :D.Hocam focus listeneri sayfaya tekrar geldiğinde yenilesin tarzında işlemler için kullanıyorum ama

Comment: You can use this logic on the class component as well with componentDidUpdate and you should check that the navigation is the same or not. It does not matter it is a class or functional component. The logic is the same.

Comment: Yes it because of info.plist .I added requires codes and works

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-screen-orientation

install the lib using

```
npm install expo-screen-orientation
```

Then on your main entry file(it could be app.js or index.js)

```
import * as ScreenOrientation from "expo-screen-orientation";
```

Then do the below to lock the orientation to landscape.

```
export default function App() {

  //Locking Orientation
  const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    lockOrientation();
  }, []);
  const lockOrientation = async () => {
    await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(
      ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT
    );
    const o = await ScreenOrientation.getOrientationAsync();
    setOrientation(o);
  };
//REST OF THE CODE
  return (
    <Components></Components>
  );
});
```